# Bitwise XOR operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

Why is this:

```js
console.log("1100" ^ "0001")
=> 1101 // as expected

console.log("1100" ^ "1001")
=> 1957 // ???
```

Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: You are using the XOR operator, but actually you seem to want the OR, since for `1101 | 0001 = 1101` (OR), while `1101 ^ 0001 = 0101` (XOR).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those numbers are interpreted as decimal numbers.

Try:

```
console.log(parseInt("1100", 2) ^ parseInt("1001", 2))
```

Of course the answer (0101) is printed in decimal (5).

The JavaScript token grammar supports numbers in decimal, octal, and hex, but not binary. Thus:

```
console.log(0xC0 ^ 0x09)
```

The first one worked, by the way, because 1100 (decimal) is 1101 (decimal) after the xor with 1.